# Asterisk catch a Incoming call and transfer it to a specific exten

Tags: asterisk

I have been building a Window Form desktop application using C# that interfaces with Asterisk using Asterisk.NET.
My first problem is catch a Incoming call and transfer it to specific exten.
The first my idea is using OriginateAction, when a call come, I use Dial event and catch it and use OriginateAction to call to a specific exten.

```
RedirectAction originateAction = new RedirectAction();

originateAction.Channel = e.Channel;
originateAction.Context = "default";
originateAction.Exten = "203";
originateAction.Priority = 1;

ManagerResponse originateResponse = manager.SendAction(originateAction);
Console.WriteLine(originateResponse);
```

But it not work like my wish.
The second my idea is using RedirectAction:

```
RedirectAction originateAction = new RedirectAction();

originateAction.Channel = e.Channel;
originateAction.Context = "default";
originateAction.Exten = "203";
originateAction.Priority = 1;

ManagerResponse originateResponse = manager.SendAction(originateAction);
Console.WriteLine(originateResponse);
```

And it not work.

I have find on many websites but the documents is very little.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly share with us the solution per your comment on QuickDanger

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using some kind of dynamic dialplan instead of "catching" calls reactively. Why not use an AGI script?

Essentially, your application tells a database or other central system what to do when calls matching certain criteria come in. Then Asterisk runs the script you setup when calls reach a certain context (such as all incoming calls), and then the script routes the call dynamically based on the inputs given by your application.

Since you seem to like .NET, here's a .NET AGI project to help you get started: [AsterNET](https://github.com/skrusty/AsterNET). It looks like the library you mentioned, [Asterisk.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asterisk-dotnet/), is also capable of Fast CGI (what AGI uses), but the last release was in 2009, whereas AsterNet is active as recently as 3 months ago.

I personally use [phpAGI](http://eder.us/projects/phpagi/) to do all kinds of neat ACD and call routing stuff in our call center.

For more info on AGI, see the [official docs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_AGI).

**Edit:**
I should probably also explain some basic call flow terminology (from the docs):

- Originate: Generates an outgoing call to a Extension/Context/Priority or Application/Data. Example: User clicks a button, Originate a call to their desk phone, when they answer that call, it executes dialplan, or a dialplan application.
- Redirect: Redirect (transfer) a call. Example: Agent and Customer are talking, but Manager wants to take over the call. Use Redirect to "take" the call from Agent and ring the Manager.
- Dial: (in dialplan only, not AMI) Dial the technology/channel specified. Note that you can only *Originate* from your .NET application, not Dial.

Can you show your event handler code? It looks like that library would say something like `manager.NewChannel += new ManagerEventHandler(new_channel);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't care my technology I using, I only want to know idea for catch a Incoming call and transfer it to a specific exten, what's actions I should use?

Comment: Thanks @QuickDanger, I just found solution for this issue! :)

Comment: @PhongTình what is the solution you found care to share?